# Select and delete data row using radio input in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've seen many solutions (all of which did not work for me) for using a check-box input to select and delete multiple rows in a database table, so I've also tried a radio input to select only one.

It still doesn't work and is not displaying any error messages for me using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `init_set('display errors', 1);`

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, phone, email, website, how, reg_date FROM myTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><thead><th></th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th><th>Hearsay</th><th>Last Updated</th><th>Update?</th></thead><tbody>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" value=\"<?php echo \$row['id']?>\"></td><td>" .$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["phone"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td>".$row["website"]."</td><td>".$row["how"]."</td><td>".$row["reg_date"]."</td><td><a href=\"update.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Update</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    $msgwindow = "0 results";
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) { //check if you received the post

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $radio);
    $radio = $_POST['radio'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $msgwindow = "Success: Record Deleted";
}
else{
    $msgwindow = "Error";
}

$conn->close();
```

To highlight, here's the input for the radio button:

```
<input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" value=\"<?php echo \$row['id']?>\">
```

The form (located in another PHP file, this one is called in using include) seems to acknowledge the button pushed for delete, but nothing happens.

```
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <?php include('myTableData.php'); ?>           
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Data" id="delete">       
    </form>
```

Comment: Well, if the `<input>` isn't inside of your `<form>` in the DOM, it's unlikely the browser will send it to PHP. That may be your actual problem.

Comment: Will edit post to include how both the input radio and input submit is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already inside PHP and you're using PHP tags and echo in
`value=\"<?php echo \$row['id']?>\">` and inside your `while` loop.

Remove the `<?php echo` and `?>` from it.

Change it to:

```
value='".$row["id"]."'>
```

or

```
value=\"" . {$row['id']} . "\">
```

I'm quite surprised that error reporting didn't throw/catch that syntax error.

However, you have this other piece of code shown separately below:

```
<input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio\" name=\"radio\" value=\"<?php echo \$row['id']?>\">
```

---

If you're not inside PHP, then you need to remove all of the `\` slashes from it.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
```

- So I'm unsure as to if that was taken partly from your echo'd statement or is a separate piece of code.

Comment: Thank you! The format value='".$row["id"]."'> worked. The other did not.

Comment: @ergargh  you're welcome. Yeah, I had a funny feeling about that other one, which is why I included the other just in case.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="db_trnas" value="Add" />Add
<input type="radio" name="db_trnas" value="Delete" />Delete
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['db_trans'])){
    if($_POST['db_trans']=='add'){
        //do db insert stuff
    } else if($_POST['db_trans']=='delete'){
        // do db delete stuff
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden field and get hidden field value on submit
        \"/>

```
    if(isset($_POST['hdnId'])) { //check if you received the post


    }
```